# Bsurface error problem

Tags: modeling, add-on

Encountered this error. Few times already. Am i stupid or it has a real problem?[image]

Comment: Please flesh this out a bit. We can't do much with that little information. When do you encounter this error? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: That is most likely some sort of error in the addon, and should probably be reported to the author of the script.

Comment: Well. Im doing retopology of a character. And with help of this addon drawing a low poly mesh. It worked fine before. But today i encountered this bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had similar issues with Bsurfaces and it is difficult to pin point what triggers the error. The solution that works for me is making sure the automatic join is not ticked.

[image]

For the record: The error, when it happens, generates a number of overlapping files which essentially corrupt further work - specifically 4 files. In my case here only the Plane [green] can be considered not corrupt and the only one worth saving. I would advise that the other items be deleted, your file saved and Blender restarted.

[image]